# xeditable onbeforesave not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm having issues with the xeditable directive. The onbeforesave is not firing, even though the in-place editing works fine on the client side. I can't get any reaction out of either onbeforesave or onaftersave.

I've included angular version 1.5.0 in my project.
I'm setting up the element like this, it's in a table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobs">
  <td>{{ job._id }}<i ng-click="removeJob(job._id)" class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
  <td>{{ job.title }}</td>
  <td editable-text="job.description" onbeforesave="alert('hello');">{{ job.description || "empty" }}</td>
</tr>
```

But I haven't been able to make the alert go off when clicking save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#onbeforesave):

> One way to submit data on server is to define `onbeforesave` attribute pointing to some method of scope

The `onbeforesave` is taking in a scope method, so `alert('hello')` in this case is trying to call some `$scope.alert` method that doesn't exist. To make this work try something like

```
// in your controller

$scope.test = function(data) {
    alert(data);
};

// in your template

<tr ng-repeat="job in jobs">
  <td>{{ job._id }}<i ng-click="removeJob(job._id)" class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
  <td>{{ job.title }}</td>
  <td editable-text="job.description" onbeforesave="test($data)">{{ job.description || "empty" }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I was using a scope method earlier but wanted to simplify by putting in an alert.. seems like I messed up on my first attempt because now when I put in a scope method it worked. Thanks @jpopseculian

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `e-form` as shown below (I just extracted the wrong code snippet only).

*Html*

```
<td editable-text="job.description" e-form="tableform" 
onbeforesave="checkJob(job)">{{ job.description || "empty" }}</td>
```

*JS*

```
 $scope.checkJob= function(data) {

   //your logic

  };
```